# How to get a of most recent posts/messages with the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, web-applications, rest, facebook-graph-api

The Graph API lets you obtain the "top news" for a given user, via the `"/home"` connection type. But how do you obtain the "Most recent"?

I also [asked this on the facebook forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=296518#p296518)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/home is the most recent from the looks of it. I just tested /me/home and it's the same as my "most recent" feed on the front end. You never know with Facebook though. Data is never reliable.

Comment: it wasn't when I tested it a few weeks ago. But things change indeed. :) I've also asked this in the facebook forum (http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=296518#p296518).